# Algebraic/Geometric multiplicity of a polynomial expression of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix and $p(x)$ a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$. How is the algebraic and geometric multiplicity of some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ related to the respective multiplicities of $p(\lambda)$ (as an eigenvalue of $p(A)$)?

By reducing to the case where $A$ is in Jordan canonical form, I think I've shown that algebraic multiplicity is preserved. I also think I can show that geometric multiplicity of $p(\lambda)$ (as an eigenvalue of $p(A)$) is at most the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ (as an eigenvalue of $A$).

I wanted to first check that the above claims were correct, and if so, whether there's a sharper bound for the geometric multiplicity of $p(\lambda)$.

Thanks!

Comment: algebraic multiplicity is not preserved. If $A$ has $1$ and $-1$ as simple eigenvalues, and $p(x) = x^2$, then $A^2$ has $1$ as eigenvalue with multiplicity 2

Comment: Also, let $J$ be a jordan block relative to eigenvalue $0$ and again $p(x) =x^2$. $0$ is a eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity 1 for $J$, but it has geometric multiplicity 2 in $J^2$

Comment: I see, thanks for the counterexamples. Does this mean that the multiplicities of $p(\lambda)$ are always bounded below by the respective multiplicities of $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, that is true